# what is dominate factor for disk price?

Tags: performance, architecture, storage, disk

What is dominate factor of the disk price, capacity or [IOPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS)? I think the answer of this question should also answer [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093694/five-minutes-rules-the-price-of-one-access-of-disc-i-o) in which i asked why cost of disc I/O per access is **PricePerDiskDrive/AccessesPerSecondPerDisk**.

Thanks

Chang

Answer (score 1):

The factor dominating the price is the market segment: Home disks are cheapest, server disks most expensive.

Comment: I think my question isn't business oriented but technique. what's  dominate factor make home disks is cheaper than server discs? speed or capacity?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on several factors, as stated in the previous answer, you have the segment, home or business.

Then there is the architecture:

- SCSI (bus controller with high speeds)
- SSD (flash)
- SATA (regular drive)
- SAS (serial attached scsi, backwards compatible with SATA)

SAS and SCSI are mostly disks running at high speeds, this makes them more expensive.

SATA disks for home use at normal speeds (5400 or 7200 rpm) are expensive based on capacity and brand. If a company has the first 3 TB disk it will be very expensive, when 3 companies have those disks, prices will decrease because of competition

SSD is a technology that got affordable, but still a lot more expensive than regular SATA (with platters). This is because there are no turning parts and it uses faster memory.

Also a very nice thing to remember :

The faster the drive, the more expensive, there for it is normal that the better your IOPS are the more expensive it is.

Capacity has a price, but it is linked to the drives speed and the recent evolution in technology.